# Cannot get Modal in Bootstrap 5 to open up using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm currently trying to create a loading dialog with bootstrap 5.

So the first thing I did is copied to the dialog from the documentation into my test html:

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" id = "waitDialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   Some Stuff. 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then I wrote a bit of JS to try to open it up following the instructions in the documentation

```
  var myModal = document.getElementById('waitDialog');
  var modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(myModal)
  modal.show();
```

This is comming straight from the documetation at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

I doesn't work because modal is null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

First, the `getInstance` method returns the modal instance associated with the DOM element, since it returns `null`, it means the modal has not been initialized.
There's another method `getOrCreateInstance`, which should create the instance if none was found (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#getorcreateinstance).

Second, the modal element is the containing `div` with the classname of `modal` not the one with id `waitDialog`.

So ideally, your code should look something like this https://jsfiddle.net/7m1oqc9d/3/

```js
var myModal = document.getElementById('staticBackdrop');
var modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(myModal)
modal.show()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" id="waitDialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   Some Stuff. 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are missing `new` keyword. Second, you call `bootstrap.Modal` function passing it element with wrong id.

This code will work :

```
var myModal = document.getElementById("staticBackdrop");
  var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(myModal);
  modal.show();
```